# What is the following class function trying to achieve?

Tags: objective-c, swift, class

I am trying to convert the following piece of open source Objective C code to swift, but I am having a tough time wrapping my head around what this class function is trying to achieve. I know its a class method, I have added what I rewrote it at the bottom.

```
+ (instancetype)eventWithTitle:(NSString *)title day:(NSUInteger)day startHour:(NSUInteger)startHour durationInHours:(NSUInteger)durationInHours
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithTitle:title day:day startHour:startHour durationInHours:durationInHours];
}
```

Here is the method it is referencing if that helps.

```
- (instancetype)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title day:(NSUInteger)day startHour:(NSUInteger)startHour durationInHours:(NSUInteger)durationInHours
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        _title = [title copy];
        _day = day;
        _startHour = startHour;
        _durationInHours = durationInHours;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Swift Version

```
    class func eventWithTitle(title: String, day: UInt32, startHour: UInt32, durationInHours: UInt32) {

        self.init(title: title, day: day, startHour: startHour, durationInHours: durationInHours)
    }

    init(title: String, day: UInt32, startHour: UInt32, durationInHours: UInt32) {

        self.title = title
        self.day = day
        self.startHour = startHour
        self.durationInHours = durationInHours

    }
```

The error I get when running this code is the following:

> Result of initializer is unused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> **Class Factory Methods and Convenience Initializers**
>
> For consistency and simplicity, Objective-C class factory methods are
>   imported as convenience initializers in Swift. This allows them to be
>   used with the same syntax as initializers.

That means, there is only the convenience initializer, the factory method is dropped.

```
init(title : String, day : Int, startHour : Int, durationInHours : Int)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. That means the class function eventWithTitle does not need to be created? Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Exactly. The factory methods come from a time with manual memory management for convenience reasons. That's obsolete in Swift

Comment: I tried this solution as well, this looks good. I am just getting initalizer is unused warning. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

It's basically just a factory method. As you'll notice in the Objective-C version, the alloc'd/init'd instance is returned from that method. So you're going to want to change your Swift function to be more like:

```
class func eventWithTitle(title: String, day: UInt32, startHour: UInt32, durationInHours: UInt32) -> <className>{

    return <className>(title: title, day: day, startHour: startHour, durationInHours: durationInHours)
}
```

Comment: ty, I didn't see this before my refresh.